# Always Show Mouse Over Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, mouse

I'm working on a javascript/canvas game, and using mouse position to determine what blocks to dig. Whenever I use the movement controls the mouse disappears though, which is annoying because then I have stop moving and move the mouse to see its position again.

So I'm looking for a way to make the mouse always visible on the canvas, opposite to using CSS `cursor: none` to make it invisible.

Full project here: https://gist.github.com/TuckerFlynn/0a52278878a888b0f695

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that would work with this situation no matter what is happening within the canvas, but I'll add my code to the question anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mouse can certainly navigate off-canvas, so...

1. Hide the mouse when it's over the canvas.
2. Draw your own "fake cursor" following the current mouse position reported by canvas's `mousemove`.
3. If the mouse leaves the canvas, just leave the fake cursor visible as a reminder of the mouse's last canvas position.

Your "fake" canvas cursor doesn't have to look like a mouse. It could even be a simple cross. Or if you really want it to look like a mouse, then move an image of a mouse around the canvas.